# python 3-pandas-can not save url dat to excel, get below error message

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py:836: UserWarning: Ignoring URL 'http://vip.104.com.tw/9/module/download_file.cfm?x=010000100100577535930010341740564056332332333417000009990000F3F3FFFF066690009C68939735553FFF9000RJSS&w=0101101101017CA57B481011291675917591667676632916101999991016C74FFFFF6666000F98CF67300109EFE90000RJSS&t=1&d=000001000000735539750100315653465346323333333156RJSS&i=010001100100F733FB730110920390739073322332339203RJSS&custno=53091079000&CFID=230696393&CFTOKEN=92e80c7cdbf8963e-C0E390CF-049F-FAF7-CF37CD44F16D19D6' with link or location/anchor > 255 characters since it exceeds Excel's limit for URLS
**

```
df = DataFrame({'姓名': xa, '年紀': xb,'性別': xc,'代碼': xd,'照片連結': xe,'最近工作': xf0,'居住地': xf1,'E-mail': xf2,'聯絡電話': xf3,'英文姓名': xf4,'基本資料': xf5,'身高體重': xf6,'擅長工具': xf7,'最高學歷': xf8,'附件': xg,'推薦人': xh,'工作經歷一': xi,'工作經歷二': xj,'工作經歷三': xk,'工作經歷四': xl,'工作經歷五': xm})
df.to_excel('104履歷.xlsx',sheet_name='sheet1', index=True)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The warning is hidden by the long url but it says:

> **UserWarning**: Ignoring URL ... with link or location/anchor > 255 characters since it exceeds Excel's limit for URLS

This is warning that Excel has a limit of 255 characters for urls and for url anchors and doesn't allow urls longer than that.

You can avoid the warning by using an XlsxWriter constructor option to treat urls as strings:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('example.xlsx',
                        engine='xlsxwriter',
                        options={'strings_to_urls': False})

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

writer.save()
```

**Update**: As of XlsxWriter version 1.2.3 Excel's newer limit of 2079 characters is supported by default.